# how to check MS Word page margins using vba script?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have to check many Word document for the following:
 Margins: left = right = top = bottom = a specific value e.g. (0.5 inches)

I am trying to write a small vba script that would report the above. I have just started and at the moment have been able to find about `ActiveDocument.PageSetup` which offers 4 properties for each of the four margins. I am very new to VBA, and checking for equality did not work for me, this is what i have tried:

```
Sub check()
  With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
     If (.LeftMargin = .RightMargin = .TopMargin = .BottomMargin = 72) Then
       MsgBox ("all margins equal to 72 points")
     Else
       MsgBox ("one or more margins not set to 72 points")
     End If  
  End With  
End Sub
```

I keep getting the message under the `Else`. Would appreciate all the help.

Comment: You can't check the values in this way... try this `If (.LeftMargin = 72 AND .RightMargin = 72 AND .TopMargin = 72 AND .BottomMargin = 72) Then`

Comment: @Baro this works for points value 72 but if i need to check for margin value 0.78 inches = 56.15 points it doesn't work, any suggestions?

Comment: The `Margin` values are `Single` and it accept the dot as decimal separator. For example: `If (.LeftMargin = 56.15 AND .RightMargin = 56.15 AND .TopMargin = 56.15 AND .BottomMargin = 56.15) Then`. If this not work, probably your marings aren't `56.15`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than manually converting everything to points, use Word's 'InchesToPoints' function. For example:

```
Sub CheckMargins()
Dim StrMrgn As String, sMrgn As Single, StrOut As String
StrMrgn = InputBox("What is the required margin, in inches?", "Margin checker")
If Not IsNumeric(StrMrgn) Then Exit Sub
sMrgn = InchesToPoints(CSng(StrMrgn))
MsgBox sMrgn
With ActiveDocument.PageSetup
  If (.LeftMargin = sMrgn) And (.RightMargin = sMrgn) And (.TopMargin = sMrgn) And (.BottomMargin = sMrgn) Then
       StrOut = "All margins"
     Else
       StrOut = "One or more margins not"
     End If
End With
MsgBox StrOut & " equal to " & StrMrgn & " inches."
End Sub
```